# No. of perfect squares between 1 and A such that A>=1 is equal to integral part of sqrt[A]. Could someone help me understand why this works?

Tags: math, logic

No. of perfect squares between 1 and A such that A>=1 is equal to integral part of sqrt[A].
I tried few examples to convince myself but still could someone help me understand why this works?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Do you want a formal mathematical proof, or an intuition?

Comment: Note that this question is better-suited for https://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Call `a` the integral part of sqrt(A).

If `b` is an integer such that `1 <= b <= a`, then `b²` is a perfect square between 1 and A.

Conversely, if `B` is a perfect square between 1 and A, then there exists a unique nonnegative integer `b` such that `b² = B`, and from `1 <= B <= A` it follows that `1 <= b <= a`.

Thus there is a bijection between the following two sets:

- The set of perfect squares between 1 and `A`;
- The set of integers between 1 and `a`.

The number of integers between 1 and `a` is equal to `a`. Thus the number of perfect squares between 1 and `A` is equal to `a`.